# Build simple App to drive and view results of a Spark batch job

Tags: apache-spark

I am looking for a good approach (possibly with an example) to:

Build simple App to drive and view results of a Spark batch job.

So basically I am looking to:

1. Launch a spark batch job from a driver program/App.
2. Save results of the spark batch job when it ends, to a database.
3. The Driver program/App needs to be notified when spark job
   completes.
4. The driver program can then display or process the results of the
   spark job.

Steps 1 and 3 are the key steps for which I am looking for guidance.

I am thinking this must have been done well before; and I am looking to build on the solution. Hence the question.

Look forward to your response.

Comment: How far have you gotten with step 1 on your own?

Comment: Look at Spark documentation Deploy section.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below example it will help you in building the solution:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestRun");
JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaRDD<String> lines = ctx.textFile("file:///myFile", 1);

lines.foreach(new VoidFunction<String>() {

    @Override
    public void call(String v1) throws Exception {
        // 2nd Point Write logic to store in database
    }
});

// This line gets executed in driver to end the job.
ctx.stop();

// Here Write you logic to process the result.
```

1. You can run this program using the spark-submit command. Follow [Submitting Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) to know How to submit it.
2. You can write your logic in **`foreach`** action block of code to write the code.
3. The Logic which is stopping the context gets executed when batch job ends.
4. You can write your logic that needs to be executed when job ends just after this **`ctx.stop`** call.